# How do I create a custom gameobject (combining a sphere and a cube)

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

Asking SO because the unity forums are very slow.

I'm making a predator / prey game.  I want the prey agents to be spheres with a cube as a tail.  Basically I want to make my own gameobject made out of a connected cube and sphere.

How do I create a custom gameobject?

Answer (score 2):

Can not quite catch what do you want. But maybe create a empty gameObject and drag your cube and sphere into it as "sub-gameObjects" will work?

Menu -> GameObject -> Create Empty, then drag the gameObjects you want to connect together to the new created "GameObject".

Comment: True, and  you can name that Emtpy GameObject. It'll be 1 object, with his childs being a cube and a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Another common way is to create a [Prefab](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html) the holds your pair of `GameObjects`.

For example you can do the following :

1. create a `GameObject` called `PreyAgent` and add to it 2 children (the
   cube and the sphere).
2. Right click on the project window and select `Create->Prefab` and give it a name (es. `PreyAgentPrefab`)
3. Drag and drop the PreyAgent `GameObject` from `Hierarchy` window to the created Prefab.

Once created the prefab you can instantiate it from code this way:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("PreyAgentPrefab")) as GameObject;
```

This is useful to create common objects that you want to use across different scenes or projects.